# Replacing UIBezierPath with new scaled path

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibezierpath

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIBezierPath` that stretches across the cell.  When my `tableview` goes into editing mode, a portion of the right end of the path goes off the screen when the cell is shifted over.  My solution is to scale the path down when I go into edit mode, then scale it back up to its original size when coming out of edit mode.  I tried this out and the new scaled down path appears, but the original wider path is still visible.  Basically, the new scaled down path is drawn over the original wider path.  How can I toggle between two paths to make one disappear and the other one visible.

```
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super didTransitionToState:state];


    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.waveView.frame.origin.x, self.waveView.frame.origin.y, self.waveView.frame.size.width -100, self.waveView.frame.size.height);

        //Using +100/-100 for testing

        CGFloat scaleFactor = (self.waveView.frame.size.width-100)/self.waveView.frame.size.width;

        self.waveView.frame = newFrame;

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.waveView.transform,
                                                         scaleFactor,
                                                         1);

        [self.waveView.path applyTransform:transform];

    }
    else if (state ==UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask)
    {

    // normal mode : back to normal

        CGRect originalFrame = CGRectMake(self.waveView.frame.origin.x, self.waveView.frame.origin.y, self.waveView.frame.size.width +100, self.waveView.frame.size.height);

        CGFloat scaleFactor = (self.waveView.frame.size.width + 100)/self.waveView.frame.size.width;

        self.waveView.frame = originalFrame;

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.waveView.transform,
                                                         scaleFactor,
                                                         1);

        [self.waveView.path applyTransform:transform];



    }

}
```

waveView is a subclass of `UIView` with the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer* blueWave;

-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.blueWave = [self createShapeLayer];
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.blueWave];
    [self render];
}

- (void)render 
{
    self.blueWave.path = self.path.CGPath;
}

- (CAShapeLayer *) createShapeLayer 
{
    CAShapeLayer* layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    layer.lineWidth = 2;
    layer.fillColor = nil;

    return layer;
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndex` I do the following

```
cell.waveView.path = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:pathData];
```

Comment: What is waveView? Is it a UIView subclass?

Comment: @rdelmar yes.  forgot to mention that.

Comment: So what is path? Is that a bezier path that you draw in waveView's drawRect method? I tried to duplicate your problem, but couldn't. I added a subview called WaveView to my cell, and drew a bezier path in its drawRect method. When I put the cell into edit mode, the path shrinks appropriately with no code needed.

Comment: @rdelmar so when you shrink down the path, you only have one path visible?  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I initially set the path `cell.waveView.path = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:pathData];` then when edit mode is initiated I attempt to scale down.

Comment: Yes, I only see one path. I have my waveView pinned to all 4 sides of the cell's contentView, so it shrinks horizontally when the cell goes in to edit mode. I'm not shrinking the path explicitly -- I don't use any code to do this.

Comment: @rdelmar So you're able to get the path to automatically shrink horizontally without a scale transform?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65995/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-brosef).